# Cannot store file content in hashicorp vault using Vault kv put

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to add file content in vault using vault kv put but I am unable to add data in vault

`vault kv put -format=json -address ${VAULT_ADDR} key=@abc.json`
Here the error says "**Must supply data**"

I also tried various other options like -

`vault kv put -format=json -address ${VAULT_ADDR} key @abc.json`
Here key is being added into vault address url e.g vault-address/key

&

`vault kv put -format=json -address ${VAULT_ADDR} @abc.json`
Here error says "Must supply data"

My Json file is sample test file and has following content in it

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "baz"
}
```

Can someone please help me solving this issue?

Comment: The second command is the correct usage, but you claim it does not deliver the desired result. What do you expect to be different from its result?

Comment: I am expecting that abc.json content should be added into key in vault but when I tried the key was appended to vault address and thus giving me error since the vault address was wrong and should not have /key at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create secret without -format=json. The below command worked for me.

```
vault kv put app/dev/test @test.json
```